# How to display multiple select attribute values in product detail page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I am using Magento 2.3

I have an attribute named "Test" and input type for this attribute is multiple select. I have displayed the selected values of this attribute in product detail page. Please refer below screenshot:

[image]

These are the selected attribute values in one of the products. Now I want to display them in custom format just like below screenshot:

[image]

Desired Format:

```
<a href="">attribute value</a>
```

I have set this attribute in Layered navigation as well

[image]

We all know that when we click on any attribute value in layered navigation then filter will be applied and corresponding products with the same attribute values will be shown

So I want the same functionality for the values which I have displayed in product detail page in "More Information" tab. So How can I achieve this?

It means I want to display each values as a hyperlink and when we click on any of the attribute value then I want it to work like Layered navigation that I have explained above.

Answer (score 0):

First Go to Admin panel,

Click on `Stores -> Attributes -> Product` from left side menu.

Click on Attribute you want to display inside details page.

Now click on `Storefront Properties` tab from left sidebar,
Set `Yes on Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront`.

`Details` tab display description of product, which is set from admin product.

Now your value display inside more information tab.
clear cache.